# can't find variable name when its inside an if statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

after running a graphql query, I extract some values from the result into an object and use it in my flat list.

```
const DATA = data.users.nodes[0].userRelations.map(
      (item: { relatedUser: { firstName: string; id: number } }) => ({
        id: item.relatedUser.id,
        imageUrl: defaultUrl,
        name: item.relatedUser.firstName,
      }),
    );
```

This works. However, when I change it to something like this:

```
  const { error, data, refetch } = useUsersQuery({
    variables: {
      where: { id: 1 },
    },
  });

  if (data) {
    const DATA = data.users.nodes[0].userRelations.map(
      (item: { relatedUser: { firstName: string; id: number } }) => ({
        id: item.relatedUser.id,
        imageUrl: defaultUrl,
        name: item.relatedUser.firstName,
      }),
    );
  } else {
    const DATA = [
      {
        id: 'bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad53abb28ba',
        imageUrl: defaultUrl,
        name: 'Johann',
      },
      {
        id: '3ac68afc-c605-48d3-a4f8-fbd91aa97f63',
        imageUrl: defaultUrl,
        name: 'Lars',
      },
      {
        id: '58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d72',
        imageUrl: defaultUrl,
        name: 'Sarah',
      },
    ];
  }


...
<FlatList
          data={DATA}
          horizontal={true}
          scrollEnabled
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <WhitelistItem title={item.name} face={item.imageUrl} />
          )}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        />
```

I start getting an error here `data={DATA}` that `Cannot find name 'DATA'. Did you mean 'data'?`. Why is this so? Even if the query fails, I am still creating a `DATA` variable in the else statement. So why is not being detected here? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  let DATA;
  if (data) {
    DATA = data.users.nodes[0].userRelations.map(
      (item: { relatedUser: { firstName: string; id: number } }) => ({
        id: item.relatedUser.id,
        imageUrl: defaultUrl,
        name: item.relatedUser.firstName,
      }),
    );
  } else {
    DATA = [
      {
        id: 'bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad53abb28ba',
        imageUrl: defaultUrl,
        name: 'Johann',
      },
      {
        id: '3ac68afc-c605-48d3-a4f8-fbd91aa97f63',
        imageUrl: defaultUrl,
        name: 'Lars',
      },
      {
        id: '58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d72',
        imageUrl: defaultUrl,
        name: 'Sarah',
      },
    ];
  }
```

`let` and `const` are block scope, which means they are not defined outside the block (the curly brackets) in which they are declared. When you declare `DATA` inside your if/else, it's only declared inside there.